# How can I fail CoCreateInstanceEx, CoInitializeSecurity, CoSetProxyBlanket, WMI calls

Tags: c++, unit-testing, com, wmi

I am executing tests as part of my unit test project. 
I wanted to know is there any way to fail the following calls :

CoCreateInstance
CoInitializeSecurity
CoSetProxyBlanket
WMI Calls

I want to do this as a administator user without have access to any code like for e.g stopping any service, or removing any dlls

I have to do this so that the negative code coverage increases.

Can anyone please help me :)

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

`CoCreateInstance`: You can easily fail by tinkering with the registry. For example, if you are initializing a WMI class, find that class in registry and rename its keys and values. Be sure to make a backup first.

`CoInitializeSecurity`: I haven't tried it but I am pretty sure that you can fail it with a less privileged user. For example, a user who doesn't have admin access would not be able to get the HDD serial no.

`CoSetProxyBlanket`: Again, I think you can fail it by a less privileged user. But I am not sure about this one.

Comment: thanks a lot :) can you please tell me which registry node i need to look for

Answer (score 0):

You can easily fail `CoInitializeSecurity` simply by calling it twice in a row.  The second call will fail with 0x80010119 (RPC_E_TOO_LATE).